# How to get SSID (Network name) in iOS Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am looking for a solutions to get iOS wifi mac SSID (network name ) from Nativescript. For Android, we have already implemented solution.

Nativescript iOS wifi mac even via the package **LanScan** on real devices show No Wi-Fi Available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo) to read SSID on iOS. If I'm not wrong the **nativescript-lan-scan** plugin internally uses the same.

As mentioned in Apple's official documentation on above link, since iOS 12 you will have enable **Access WiFi Information capability** from your entitlements file.

Comment: can you please share a code snippet that can point out the solution? I really need it fast. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the same plugin, just add the **Access WiFi Information capability**.